# What's the best way to keep JWT tokens safely saved locally in flutter apps?

Tags: flutter, jwt, token

Not just where save the token (eg: SQLite, Hive...), but also how (libs, best practices)?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You probably don't want to store sensitive data in shared preferences. Instead you might want to look into a plugin like this:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_secure_storage

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

// Create storage
final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

// Write value 
await storage.write(key: 'jwt', value: token);
```

Comment: flutter_secure_storage does not support web for now. Any other alternative with flutter web support ?

Comment: @fvisticot I know that the question was asked more than a year ago but I leave the answer for posterity. Basically, there is no way to store token in encrypted storage on the web. But IMO it's safe enough to use shared preferences (actually localStorage) as a fallback for the web.

Comment: An HTTP-only cookie might be safer against XSS than localStorage if your server can provide it. IIRC, these cookies can also be used with fetch as well for SPAs. I'm not a security expert though so please read about this.

Comment: flutter_secure_storage support web , windows, linux, Macos, android and IOS now from april 2022

Answer (score 19):

As I mentioned on a deleted post, I've been using hive to storage my tokens and other local data. With [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) it's possible to create [an encrypted box](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/advanced/encrypted_box)

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

void main() async {
  var keyBox = await Hive.openBox('encryptionKeyBox');
  if (!keyBox.containsKey('key')) {
    var key = Hive.generateSecureKey();
    keyBox.put('key', key);
  }

  var key = keyBox.get('key') as Uint8List;
  print('Encryption key: $key');

  var encryptedBox = await Hive.openBox('vaultBox', encryptionKey: key);
  encryptedBox.put('secret', 'Hive is cool');
  print(encryptedBox.get('secret'));
}
```

As mentioned in comments:

The example above stores the encryption key in an unencrypted box. You should NEVER do that.

Important:

- Only values are encrypted while keys are stored in plaintext.
- Make sure to store the encryption key securely when your application is closed. With Flutter you can use the [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) or a similar package.
- There is no check if the encryption key is correct. If it isn't, there may be unexpected behavior.

> So, if you don't need any of `hive` specific features, [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) should be a better option for you.

Comment: Can this encrypted box be shared among two apps?

Comment: You are using an unencrypted box to store the encryption key. Defeats the purpose of using the encrypted box.

Comment: As per [Hive documentation](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/advanced/encrypted_box), when using an encrypted box you'll need to save the encryption key securely. In Flutter, they suggest [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage#-readme-tab-) so that you can save it. 
**My suggestion:** Go with this option instead.

Comment: @BrenoTeodoro yes.

Comment: Is secure storage really necessary on mobile and desktop? since in web we commonly store jwt token in a HttpOnly cookie, user can still see the content from dev tools, so I guess that unless for flutter web, you can store the jwt (not user and password, that's sensitive data) anywhere (Hive, SQLite, Get Storage, etc), in android there's a encrypted app-specific location that only your app has access, https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Answer (score 6):

I use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage for saving JWT token in local storage.

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

final storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

// to save token in local storage
await storage.write(key: 'token', value: data.token);

// to get token from local storage
var value = await storage.read(key: 'token');
```

other tips:

- Don't forget to re-build your app (sometimes you need to do `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`)
- make sure cocoapods install properly if you running it in iOS.
- For installing cocoapods `sudo gem install cocoapods`
- For updating cocoapods `sudo gem install cocoapods`
- in my case, I need to close and re-open the vscode after installing cocoapods.

Comment: As said in other answers this does not work for flutter web

Comment: @c-sharp-and-swiftui-devni it is now. Since November 2021 (version 5.0.0)

Answer (score -10):

Using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences is best for you, as it "provides a persistent store for simple data."

Sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _getAndSaveToken,
        child: Text('Get token'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_getAndSaveToken() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String token = await _getTokenFromHttp();
  await prefs.setInt('jwt', token);
}

Future<String> _getTokenFromHttp() async {
  // http code here
}
```

Comment: Does use more than one of this options in the same project make sense?

Comment: The package description itself indicates that "**this plugin must not be used for storing critical data**". It is best fitted for in-app preferences such as turning on/off dark mode.