# How to store the jwt token on a flutter website for the moment the site is reloaded?

Tags: flutter, authentication, web, jwt

I have a website build with flutter web that accesses an API that is also accessed by other servers in my system.
The API provides a login endpoint where you can login and get a jwt token.
My website does this ans stores the token in a variable.

So far, so good. Until a the first user opened the website and pressed the browser refresh button. This causes a restart of the fultter application so all variables are cleared.
My question is, wehre to store the token for that moment so that a user does not have to login again after a refresh.

I thought about:
Cookies, but cookies can be read by others.
Cookies, with httpOnly. The cookie is send somehow automatically to the server, but I don't know how? With the exact header parameter the API expects?
And there is the possibility of csrf attacks.

I can save to localStorage:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56657299/15537341
But is this more secure than cookies or the same thing under a different name?

Or can I save it some way encrypted with the password hardcoded in my code?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59815940/8170991

I don't need a "keep me signed in" functionality that a user is still logged in after restarting the PC.
How did you solved this?

Comment: This is more of a general web authentication question than a flutter question, so you could probably find some good answers if you widen your search. However, I have a few questions that will dictate where I direct you - does your server get the jwt token or is that done completely client-side (i.e. in flutter)? And does your server make API requests that need the JWT or does your server do those?

Comment: whoops I meant does your server make the API requests or does your client?

Comment: Someone who wan'ts to use the api (website or another server) posts to /login of the API Server to get a JWT token. Everyone with a valid JWT Token can access the API.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this question shouldn't be closed as off-topic as it is likely answered elsewhere, but as I couldn't find a single question that did a *good* job of answering, but I'm going to answer to the best of my ability anyways as it's something that *is* an important question and will probably be relevant to many people implementing flutter web.

Below I'll explain what options you have with OpenID/OAuth, but the OP has clarified that their endpoint is a simple credentials->token exchange, in which case the easiest solution is to save the token into [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) which will persist through refreshes but when the session ends. This could be complemented by the token being invalidated on the server side if it isn't used for a certain amount of time, although that requires some additional work server-side.

SessionStorage does have the limitation that it cannot be used across multiple browser tabs; this could be managed by using a same-site messaging system (or listening to localstorage) for requests for authentication which other pages could send, and any tab which is open and has a valid token could respond at which point this other tab would also save the token into local storage.

*If* OpenId/OAuth 2.0 were being used instead for authentication (as I'd initially assumed is happening since the question mentioned using JWT), you have a few options for how to implement your overall system. Option one is the more traditional way - you have your own server which runs and keeps track of session itself, but then uses OAuth to get API access to a different server and/or OpenID to get details about the user.

---

### Option 1: Traditional Server Setup

In this scenario, you have a 1-1 relation between your server and your client - this is where the "session" is kept track of. Then, regardless of whether your client is making API requests directly or passing them off to the server to be made, an `access_token` is used to make those API requests.

[image: Server Setup Diagram]

If you just have your backend server, this is really all that is needed to keep a session secure tbh - although you want to be able to handle the user's cookies being wiped by having a way for them to re-authenticate (traditionally a password, but in this case that could be re-performing the OpenID/OAuth flow or using that login endpoint).

The access_token is not saved on the client, but rather when the web page is accessed it will check against the server and retrieve it, then proceed to use it for future requests.

This is going to provide the best level of security, as you have control over the session between your server and client, especially if you keep your tokens server-side only and make the requests from there as you won't ever be exposing them to the client, but it does require knowledge about security and server set-up that many people won't have.

---

### Option 2: Client directly accesses services

A paradigm becoming more and more prevalent in the last little while is a "web app" which handles everything client-side. This can introduce some security issues, but so long as your login endpoint has implemented things properly, it isn't necessarily bad. In this scenario, (assuming OpenID/OAuth again) you perform the client-only authentication workflow which doesn't require any specific secret keys, and are passed back the `access_token` and whatnot (in JWT form). The tokens given back will be less long-lasting one than one passed to a server and might have other restrictions, but if they do what you need should be adequate.

In this scenario, you're right that you probably don't want to store the tokens in a cookie - especially from the client side, cookies aren't really designed for that. Instead, you should be using `LocalStorage` - while not perfectly secure, it *is* restricted to your domain and does have some protection. Where you're going to have to be careful is that you don't have any 3rd-party code running that you don't trust - so long as you trust that, you have a pretty good security model.

[image: Client-only auth]

Comment: Thanks for your long answer. We are not using OpenID/OAuth at the moment. You post to /login with your credentials and get a jwt. I try to decide between local storage and session cookie at the moment. Local storage seems to be better because the cookie is not send to the server unnecessarily, but it is not deleted if the user closes the browser. Is there a possibility to achieve that with local storage? My token should be deleted if the browser is closed.

Comment: ah. Interesting that it directly returns a JWT, but most of the last part should still apply. What you could use is [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) instead of localStorage - but be aware that it won't be accessible even from another tab without some work. Also, some browsers _do_ persist session even when they're closed - but there isn't really a robust client-side solution to that - you'd probably be better off having a fairly short expiry on the token, and having the token refreshed with each call to the backend

Answer (score -1):

You could use flutter [Hive](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/) for storing a jwt on the user's side along with other sensitive information. Hive encrypts the stored data and its blazing fast.

Comment: But I need some type of password for the storage, correct? And the password has to be in my code. And the javascript code can be downloaded from my server.

Comment: no no need for a password. Hive stores data in [encrypted boxes](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/advanced/encrypted_box)

Comment: which you open with an encryption key what is another word for password