Getting `PlatformException (PlatformException(AUTH_ERROR, No account is available to acquire token silently, null, null))` when using msal in Flutter
I'm needing to create the login/authorization process for a Flutter application that I'm working on and ran into this error: PlatformException (PlatformException(AUTH_ERROR, No account is available to acquire token silently, null, null))
This is my first time working with authorization / web tokens so I may be doing it completely wrong. To provide context, I'm using the msal_auth package (https://pub.dev/packages/msal_auth) as well as the flutter_secure_storage package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) to store the token that I get back.
I have an auth_gate.dart file that basically determines if the sign in page or home page (TabScreen) should be rendered depending on whether or not the user is authenticated.
auth_gate.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fti_team_member_app_v3/features/authentication/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:fti_team_member_app_v3/shared/presentation/main_app/tab_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class AuthGate extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthGate({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/png/Background_Splash.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Consumer<AuthService>(
          builder: (context, authService, child) {
            if (authService.isAuthenticated) {
              return const TabScreen();
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset('assets/images/png/logo.png'),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    const Text("TEAM MEMBER APP"),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await showAlertDialog(context, authService);
                      },
                      child: const Text('Sign In'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  showAlertDialog(BuildContext context, AuthService authService) async {...}
}

This uses an auth_service.dart file that is a provider to determine whether the user is authenticated or not / acquires their token / refresh token.
auth_service.dart
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:msal_auth/msal_auth.dart';

// Saving tokens via FlutterSecureStorage, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035587/whats-the-best-way-to-keep-jwt-tokens-safely-saved-locally-in-flutter-apps

class AuthService extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String clientId;
  final String tenantId;
  final List<String> scopes;
  late final String _authority;

  final storage = const FlutterSecureStorage(aOptions: AndroidOptions(encryptedSharedPreferences: true));
  FlutterSecureStorage get getStorage => storage;

  bool _isAuthenticated = false;
  bool get isAuthenticated => _isAuthenticated;

  AuthService({
    required this.clientId,
    required this.tenantId,
    required this.scopes,
  }) {
    // Created to allow for async initialization, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711050/load-data-asynchronously-into-changenotifier-model-in-flutter
    _init();
  }

  Future<void> _init() async {
    _authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize';

    // If token is expired, this will display the sign in screen
    if (await isTokenExpired()) {
      _isAuthenticated = false;
    } else {
      // otherwise, silently get the token / refresh the token
      await getTokenSilently();
      _isAuthenticated = true;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<MsalAuth> getMsalAuth() async {
    return await MsalAuth.createPublicClientApplication(
      clientId: clientId,
      scopes: scopes,
      androidConfig: AndroidConfig(
        configFilePath: 'assets/msal_config.json',
        tenantId: tenantId,
      ),
      iosConfig: IosConfig(authority: _authority),
    );
  }

  Future<void> getToken() async {
    try {
      // Get the authentication and access token
      final msalAuth = await getMsalAuth();
      final user = await msalAuth.acquireToken();
      final token = user?.accessToken;
      final tokenExpiresOn = user?.tokenExpiresOn;

      // Allow app to know that user is authenticated and store the token
      await saveToken(token, tokenExpiresOn.toString());
      _isAuthenticated = true;
      notifyListeners();
    } on MsalException catch (e) {
      log('Msal exception with error: ${e.errorMessage}');
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> getTokenSilently() async {
    try {
      // Get authentication and access token silently
      final msalAuth = await getMsalAuth();
      final user = await msalAuth.acquireTokenSilent();
      final token = user?.accessToken;
      final tokenExpiresOn = user?.tokenExpiresOn;

      // Allow app to know that user is authenticated and store the token
      await saveToken(token, tokenExpiresOn.toString());
      _isAuthenticated = true;
      notifyListeners();
    } on MsalException catch (e) {
      log('Msal exception with error: ${e.errorMessage}');
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    try {
      final msalAuth = await getMsalAuth();
      await msalAuth.logout();

      await storage.delete(key: 'jwt');
      await storage.delete(key: 'tokenExpiresOn');

      _isAuthenticated = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } on MsalException catch (e) {
      log('Msal exception with error: ${e.errorMessage}');
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<bool> isTokenExpired() async {
    final tokenExpiresOn = await storage.read(key: 'tokenExpiresOn');
    if (tokenExpiresOn == null ||
        int.parse(tokenExpiresOn) <= DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  Future<void> saveToken(String? token, String? tokenExpiresOn) async {
    await storage.write(
      key: 'jwt',
      value: token,
    );
    await storage.write(
      key: 'tokenExpiresOn',
      value: tokenExpiresOn.toString(),
    );
  }
}

Here's my main.dart
main.dart
import 'package:dynatrace_flutter_plugin/dynatrace_flutter_plugin.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fti_team_member_app_v3/features/authentication/presentation/auth_gate.dart';
import 'package:fti_team_member_app_v3/features/authentication/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

// TODO: Should move the clientId + tenantId to .env file?
void main() {
  Dynatrace().applyUserPrivacyOptions(
      UserPrivacyOptions(DataCollectionLevel.UserBehavior, true));
  Dynatrace().startWithoutWidget();
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AuthService(
        clientId: 'blank',
        tenantId: 'blank',
        scopes: [
          'https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read',
          // Add other scopes here if required.
        ],
      ),
      child: const MainApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: AuthGate(),
    );
  }
}

Am I going about this the right way? Why did I get the above mentioned error?
Thanks!
I tried to store the token in the app and it doesn't seem to be able to get a refresh token maybe? I'm not 100% sure.
